# Get the changing value of a php dynamically generated select

Tags: php, jquery

I am generating a select via PHP that, depending on what's given by the server, gives different options. There are 2 dropdowns on the page which is why I gave them a class as opposed to an id.

In the end, the Selects just look like this (they can both be the same, or different, as the events they handle are separate):

```
<select class="selectTixNumber">
<option value="600">1 Person</option>
<option value="1200">2 People</option>
</select>
```

I was trying to get the value of whichever updates by doing:

```
$(function(){
             $('.selectTixNumber').on('change', function(e) {
                var val = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
                console.log( val );
            });
        })
```

However, that's giving me nothing. There's nothing on the console but there's no error either. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the on change event actually firing? Try and use dev tools to ensure that it actually fires off...

Comment: @AndrewMacNaughton I was actually looking at that and it would appear it's not. If I change from 'on('change'...' to click, then I see it working but otherwise nothing. No idea why though...

Comment: I copy pasted your code into a plnkr and it works just fine... I imagine that something elsewhere is intercepting the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
 $(function(){
             $('.selectTixNumber').on('change', function(e) {
             var  Selectedpeople=$(this).children("option:selected").val();
             alert("People: " + Selectedpeople);
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$('.selectTixNumber').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
});
```